# Pulling variables out of functions in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

I have been self-teaching Python for a few weeks now and have the aim to create a script to run an equation and keep hitting walls. What I basically want to do is take an input with a unit attached i.e. 6M being 6,000,000, convert the unit into a numerical format and put that into an equation with an output.

So far I have defined a function:

```
def replaceunit(body):
    body = body.replace(str(body[-1]),str(units.get(body[-1])))
    return body
```

I have asked for the input and have a dictionary of units (shortened dictionary below):

```
    T = input("T = ")
    B = input("B = ")

    units ={'M': 1e6,    # mega
            'G': 1e9    # giga
    }
```

I then try and replace the if an M or G appears in the T or B variables:

```
    if str(T[-1]).isalpha() == True:
        replaceunit(T)
    if str(B[-1]).isalpha() == True:
        replaceunit(B)
```

After this I would like the updated T and B to be put into an equation that I define.

If I add a print action to my function I can see the values have been replaced, but have been unable to pull the corrected values through outside of the function and into another equation.

As I say, I'm very new to this, so if there's any help you can lend I'd very much appreciate it. Apologies also if this has been asked elsewhere, the few similar answers I have seen I haven't really understood the answer too.

Comment: Can you add code example of a simple "equation"?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in Python, meaning they cannot be changed in place, but rather you have to create a new string for every change. That is exactly what you did in `replaceunit` - you wrote `body = body.replace(...)` and you replaced the old reference with a new one that `replace` gave you.

`replaceunit` is also returning a new reference, so calling it should be done as `T = replaceunit(T)` and `B = replaceunit(B)` to save changes. You must not use the same variable if you want to save both the replaced and non-replaced versions of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value you returned from `replaceunit` to be the new value of `T`, you need to assign it:

```
T = replaceunit(T)
```

Note that you could skip the step of assigning `body` inside the function itself and simply return the value:

```
def replaceunit(body):
    return body.replace(str(body[-1]),str(units.get(body[-1])))
```

I would also suggest that it might be more useful to have a function that turns the user-inputted number into an actual number:

```
def parse_number(body: str) -> float:
    """Converts a string like '2G' into a value like 2000000000."""
    units ={
        'M': 1e6,    # mega
        'G': 1e9,    # giga
    }
    return float(body[:-1]) * units[body[-1]]
```

This will be necessary if you want to do any actual math with that value!